# NSManagedObject in memory even after deinitialized

Tags: swift, memory, core-data

I noticed in instruments, that whenever I create a `NSManagedObject`, at least 1 of this object stays in memory forever. I've created an empty project with 1 entity named: "Books".

The class for this entity:

```
class Books: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String

    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext, name: String) {
        let description = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Books", in: context)!
        self.init(entity: description, insertInto: context)

        self.name = name
    }

    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)): deinitialized") }
}
```

When I create several `Books`, instruments shows up several instances of `Books`:

[image: instances]

When the view controller deinitializes, I clean up the context by using:

```
deinit {
    context.registeredObjects.forEach { context.refresh($0, mergeChanges: false) }

    print("\(type(of: self)): deinitialized")
}
```

So after the view controller has been deinitialized, instruments is still showing 1 object of `Books`:

[image: persistent]

There is nothing else in the view controllers and the log is showing all the instances and controllers are deinitialized.

**Question:**
If I create many instances of various entities, then all of them will remain in memory forever. Is there a way to get rid of it so I can keep the memory "clean"?

**Edit:**
Screenshot of Visual Memory Debugger added

[image: Visual Memory Debugger]

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that the `refresh` call has nothing to do with whether an object is in memory. That code literally has no effect at all on the data you're looking at. The `refresh` call, with `mergeChanges:false` says that Core Data can convert the object back into a fault. It's property values and relationships may be dropped from memory, but the object itself remains.

As for why there's still a single instance in memory, it's because somewhere you have a reference to that object. The allocations tool won't help with that though. You'd be better off trying Xcode's [memory graph debugger](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-visual-memory-debugger/) if you're concerned. I suggest though, that unless your memory situation is extremely bad, tracking down a single 64 byte allocation is probably not a high priority.

Comment: Thanks for the great information, the link (and the link inside) is really useful. I've added a screenshot of Visual Memory Debugger. I don't really understand (yet) what everything means but I get the feeling it's just how the `NSManagedObjectContext` works and it's out of my control. And you're right, 64 byte isn't worth it. I've posted the screenshot just for curiosity, perhaps it could help me understand Core Data better.